# How to have puppet master on hostname without modifying /etc/hosts on client?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, puppet

I created an A record for my puppetmaster.  In case the puppetmaster on this ip address goes down and I have to spawn a new one from a new ip address, I can just change the ip address associated with the hostname in the A record to that of the new box.

I would like all my puppetclients to be able to connect to the new puppetmaster only by its hostname in the A record.

```
$ dig puppetmaster.mywebsite.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
puppetmaster.mywebsite.com.  300     IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

My client has the hostname `puppetclient-01` and my master has the hostname `puppetmaster`

On my puppet client I have no entries that resolve the hostname of `puppetmaster` to a particular IP in `/etc/hosts` because if `puppetmaster` goes down and I have to launch a new puppet master from a new ip, I want to avoid changing all the `/etc/hosts` files in my clients.

In `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` of `puppetclient-01` the only change I made to the defaults are adding this

```
[agent]
server = puppetmaster.mywebsite.com
```

On `puppetclient-01` I run this

```
root@puppetclient-01:~# puppet agent --test
info: Creating a new SSL key for puppetclient-01
info: Caching certificate for ca
info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for puppetclient-01
info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5): 12:34:56:78:CB:81:62:2E:5F:AB:40:54:D0:A1:37:95
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

Then on `puppetmaster` I run this

```
oot@puppetmaster:~# puppetca --sign puppetclient-01
notice: Signed certificate request for puppetclient-01
notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest puppetclient-01 at '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/puppetclient-01.pem'
```

Then on `puppetclient-01` when I attempt a puppet run

```
root@puppetclient-01:~# puppet agent --test
info: Caching certificate for puppetclient-01
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Server hostname 'puppetmaster.mywebsite.com' did not match server certificate; expected puppetmaster
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
err: Could not send report: Server hostname 'puppetmaster.mywebsite.com' did not match server certificate; expected puppetmaster
```

Why do I receive the error `Server hostname 'puppetmaster.mywebsite.com' did not match server certificate; expected puppetmaster`?

Are there any directives I need to change in `etc/puppet/puppet.conf` on either the client or master to get this to work correctly?

Comment: check your system clocks.  You will want to setup ntp.  Delete the cert on the client/server, try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you did not use the FQDN when generating the master cert. Following http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/troubleshooting.html: If `sudo puppet master --configprint certname` on the master produces `puppetmaster` rather than `puppetmaster.mywebsite.com` you'll need to:

> Re-generate the puppet master’s certificate:
>
> Stop puppet master. Delete the puppet master’s certificate, private
>   key, and public key:
>
> $ sudo find $(puppet master --configprint ssldir) -name "$(puppet
>   master --configprint certname).pem" -delete
>
> Edit the certname setting
>   in the puppet master’s /etc/puppet/puppet.conf file to match the
>   puppet master’s actual hostname, and the dns_alt_names setting in that
>   file to match any other DNS names you expect the master to need to
>   respond to. Start a non-daemonized WEBrick puppet master instance, and
>   wait for it to generate and sign a new certificate:
>
> $ sudo puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose
>
> You should stop the
>   temporary puppet master with ctrl-C after you see the “notice:
>   Starting Puppet master version 2.6.9” message. Restart the puppet
>   master.